# How can I make sure threads inside my class end after each rspec test?

Tags: ruby, rspec, jruby

I have a jruby class which contains a heartbeat that does something every certain number of seconds: (simplified code below)

```
class Client
  def initialise
    @interval = 30
    @heartbeat = Thread.new do
      begin
        loop do
          puts "heartbeat"
          sleep @interval
        end
      rescue Exception => e
        Thread.main.raise e
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And I have a range of rspec tests that instantiate this class.

At the end of each test, I would expect the object to be destroyed, but the threads seem to remain.

At the moment I've fixed this with:
client.rb:

```
def kill
    @heartbeat.kill
end
```

rspec:

```
after(:all) do
   client.kill
end
```

Which seems to do the job - but this doesn't feel like the best way to do it.

What is the best way to approach this?

Using version jruby-9.1.10.0 & rspec 3.7.0

Edit:
As per http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Thread.html I would expect the thread to normally terminate when the main thread does
In my tests I instantiate the client with

```
describe Client do
  context 'bla' do
    let(:client) do
      described_class.new
    end
    it 'blas' do
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How do you terminate the heartbeat thread in your code, i.e. outside RSpec?

Comment: I don't, I expect it to continue unless something kills the ruby process or it gets an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `after(:all)` with `after(:each)`.

Should be the correct syntax for what you want to do because `after(:all)` evaluates after all test cases have been run.

Comment: Doh, I had that in my code but managed to write the wrong one on this post. You're right though that it does what I desire - just not sure if that's how it _should_ be done

Comment: You could always stub the behavior of your class for everything you're not testing. In this case you could do away with the `after` block and then do something like `allow_any_instance_of(Thread).to receive(:new).and_call_original` and `allow_any_instance_of(Thread).to receive(:kill).and_call_original` if I'm getting your problem correctly.